# Writing std::ostringstream to file without copying?

Tags: c++, io

Given a function that takes an output stringstream as an argument:

```
void Foo(const std::ostringstream& _oss);
```

Is there any way of writing the stream buffer to a file **WITHOUT** having to call str() ?

I want to avoid copying the buffer (which str() does).

```
void Foo(const std::ostringstream& _oss);
{
  std::ofstream f("foo.bin");

  //WANT: write _oss to f without copying the buffer?
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an `operator<<()` taking a stream buffer:

```
f << _oss.rdbuf();
```

However, the buffer needs to be really big for this to make a noticeable difference. Usually, writing to disk will dominate the time needed for this anyway.

Note that I'd avoid creating identifiers with leading underscores.

Comment: That would write the buffer byte by byte, correct? Wondering if that would be slower than getting the buffer via str() and writing it one shot..

Comment: If it really is an `ostringstream`, couldn't the associated stringbuf have been constructed in output-only mode?

Comment: That works, indeed. I have an additional constraint that poses problem though -- I need to know the buffer size before writing to file since I've got special handling to do depending on size. I guess str() is my only resort..

Answer (score 0):

You can't write it to file without copying- because that's what writing to a file does, it copies it out of memory and on to the disk.

Of course, if you want to get technical about this, you *could* utilize a memory mapped file.

Comment: turbovince was trying to avoid the copying done by calling the `str()` member function.